# Dynamic typcasting as a child class

Tags: java, casting, polymorphism

I have a parent class `Parent`, and three classes extending it: `ChildOne`, `ChildTwo` and `ChildThree`, each of which overrides a method from `Parent` class. I created an array of `Parent` objects, and then dynamically (from user input) created objects of one of the child classes. After this, I need to iterate through the `Parent[]` array and want to typcast each element into it's "real" class (one of the child classes) in order to use the appropriate overriden method.
I tried creating a variable for the type of child class, like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
        try {
            Parent par = new Parent();
            par = parents[i];
            switch (par.getType()) {
                case "one":
                    ChildOne child1 = (ChildOne)par;
                    System.out.println(child1.overridenMethod());
                    break;
                case "two":
                    ChildTwo child2 = (ChildTwo)par;
                    System.out.println(child2.overridenMethod());
                    break;
                case "three":
                    ChildThree child3 = (ChildThree)par;
                    System.out.println(child3.overridenMethod());
                    break;
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            System.out.println("No child at position: " + i);
        }
    }
```

But I get an error saying `ChildThree` cannot be cast as `ChildTwo`. It appears that after the first element, which is succesfully typecast, the `par` object stays a child class object of whichever child class it was typecast to.
How can I work around this, and be able to typecast depending on the class of each object in the array?
Many thanks!

Comment: Why do use type casting? Why is polymorphism not feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Overriding means you have a method in parent and child is overriding its functionality.**

You could directly use polymorphism in your case. No need for casting:

```
for (Parent par: parents) {
    try {
        System.out.println(par.overridenMethod());
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        System.out.println("No child at position: " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: If i don't cast them as a specific `Child` object, how can I get the specific overriden method, instead of the original `Parent` method? The array is containing `Parent` objects.

Comment: Does the parent contain overridenMethod() method?

Comment: Yes, it does contain it.

Answer (score 1):

As stated before there is no need to cast, because the method you are calling on each object is already defined in class Parent. So you can simply write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
    Parent par = parents[i];
    System.out.println(par.overridenMethod());
}
```

Regarding your typecast error, my guess is that you have a mistake in your getType method. It probably returns a wrong value for one of your Child implementations and you end up in the wrong case block. Generally you should use instanceof when casting objects:

```
if(par instanceof ChildOne){
    ChildOne child1 = (ChildOne)par; 
}
```